# Magento 2 : Get pub/static File Path

Tags: magento2, paths

I need to get the file **PATH** for an image in `pub/static/[VENDOR_THEME]` folder.

Currently, I can do this by using a helper:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository $assetRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList $directoryList
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->_assetRepo = $assetRepository;
    $this->_directoryList = $directoryList;
}

public function getImagePath($image)
{
    return $this->_directoryList->getPath(DirectoryList::STATIC_VIEW) . 
        '/' . 
        $this->_assetRepo->getStaticViewFileContext()->getPath() . 
        '/' . 
        $image;
}
```

Is there any built-in Magento function which handles this, so I do not have to create my own helper?

Comment: How about your issue?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As @Khoa TruongDinh states you can use the `Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository` to get a file class `Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File`, which you can then use to get various data.

```
/** @var `Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository $assetRepository **/
 $asset = $this->assetRepository->createAsset('Magento_Catalog::images/image.png');
 $asset = $this->assetRepository->createAsset('My_Module::images/image.png');
```

To get asset in your theme folder `app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/web` simply strip the module name as below....

```
$asset = $this->assetRepository->createAsset('images/image.png');
```

See `Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File` for functions you can use to get file data.

```
// Get the file url
$asset->getUrl();

// Get the file path
$asset->getFilePath();

// Get the content of the file
$asset->getContent();
```

Comment: this code is not working in RecurringData.php

Answer (score 2):

In our block, we should try with:

```
$block->getViewFileUrl('/')
```

[image]

Take a look:

- `vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/require_js.phtml`
- `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/page/js/require_js.phtml`

**EDIT:** we can use `Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository`

For example: your image is under : `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/images/image.png`

```
/** @var `Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository $assetRepository **/

$this->assetRepository->getUrlWithParams('Vendor_Module::images/image.png', $params);
```

See more here: [Magento 2 Get image Url in controller or helper?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158361/magento-2-get-image-url-in-controller-or-helper)

Comment: I need the PATH - not the url

Comment: @minlare see my updated answer.

Comment: This code I am trying in RecurringData.php, its not working