# Magento 2 Get image Url in controller or helper?

Tags: magento2, image

How to get the image in the controller or helper. For example, the path of images folder:

```
 /app/code/Nitesh/Module/view/frontend/web/images
 /app/code/Nitesh/Module/view/frontend/web/images/image.png
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use below code for getting image url in `view`

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('Vendor_Module::images/image.png'); ?>" />
```

**UPDATE:**

```
<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/demo.jpg'); ?>
```

Comment: This answer is nice and simple. The first option worked for me.

Comment: how to get in controller file?

Answer (score 21):

To get Image Path in your Helper or Controller, you need to use

```
use Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface; // for $this->request
```

in your file.
Once you add the repository and create object `assetRepo` & `request`, call image path with function,

```
$params = array('_secure' => $this->request->isSecure());
$this->assetRepo->getUrlWithParams('Nitesh_Module::images/image.png', $params);
```

Refer to `vendor\magento\module-payment\Model\CcConfig.php::getViewFileUrl($fileId, array $params = [])` function

**EDIT**

To get correct image paths for Setup scripts, API calls and Cronjobs, you will require to add emulation like below to get correct image paths.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository $assetRepo,
    \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
    \Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation $appEmulation
)
{
    $this->assetRepo = $assetRepo;
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->appEmulation = $appEmulation;
}

public FunctionName($param){
    $this->appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId, \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, true);

    $params = array('_secure' => $this->request->isSecure());
    $this->assetRepo->getUrlWithParams('Nitesh_Module::images/image.png', $params);

    $this->appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation();
}
```

Reference: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/297121/2443

Comment: Error comes -> Notice: Undefined property: ...::$request in

Comment: got it from your reference ty

Comment: Thanks alot man. Its really helpful to getting image url.

Comment: @Jaimin, this is not working in recurringData.php, have u tried there?

Comment: @jafarpinjar, what issue you are facing? You can try without passing argument to the function call like `$this->assetRepo->getUrlWithParams('Nitesh_Module::images/image.png', [])` Please let me know if you still face any issue.

Comment: @JaiminSutariya, Yes. I'm trying in RecurringData.php, where i set Area_code as Global, so the Url is forming with _view/global which is not working, you may try once with RecurringData.php , then u you will get the idea about the issue

Comment: @JaiminSutariya, okay sure, Thanks

Comment: @jafarpinjar, you could try something like this in your code to set area code. https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/297121/2443

Comment: @JaiminSutariya, what that code does? have u faced the issue in recurringData.php?

Comment: Updated my answer, please check.