# Magento 2 - Get product image url in API

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.3, api, product-images

I am creating custom API in magento 2 and I need to get image URL of product.

I have used this code to get image URL:

```
$imageUrl = $this->listProductBlock->getImage($product,"category_page_grid")->getImageUrl();
```

Where `$this->listProductBlock` is the instance of `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct`

With this I am getting url like this: `..static/version1574919158/webapi_rest/_view/en_US/Magento_Catalog/images/product/placeholder/.jpg`

I have also tried `imageBuilder` class, but didn't work either.

Please help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add `App\Emulation` instance in your model and define `Area`. In your case the area is `AREA_FRONTEND`.

```
 namespace YourPackage\YourModule\Model;

class YourApifilename implements \YourPackage\YourModule\Api\YourApiClassName
{
    protected $appEmulation;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation $appEmulation
    )
    {

        $this->appEmulation = $appEmulation;

    }

    public Yourapimethod($param){

     $this->appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId, \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, true);

    /******** Do your work ******************/

    $this->appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation();
    }
```

**I hope this will help**

Comment: Let me try.....

Answer (score 3):

It is because you are currently in API area

You need to emulate your area to frontend. Just emulate, and after getting image you need to revert back emulation by stop emulate.

```
startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId, \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, true);
```

and

```
stopEnvironmentEmulation();
```

with `Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation` instance

Comment: Your answer is also correct but you are late +1 for that

Answer (score 2):

You can use this one.

```
protected $_productRepositoryFactory;

public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterfaceFactory $productRepositoryFactory
) {

    $this->_productRepositoryFactory = $productRepositoryFactory;
}
```

And you can get image like this way.

```
$product = $this->_productRepositoryFactory->create()->getById($item->getProductId());
$product->getData('image');
$product->getData('thumbnail');
$product->getData('small_image');
```

Comment: I am getting product collection. It wont be good to load each product in loop, it would slow down my API. Thanks for the answer though

Comment: so you mean that you are working on whole product collection. I thought that you need only one product image path.