# Magento 2 Get pub/static File Path

Tags: magento2, static-content

I am trying to add a link into the HTML head from (content/configuration/html) head section in the backend(admin) to a file that's located in my `pub/static/version*****/frontend/` folder.

How can I link to this folder without using an absolute path?

Thanks

Comment: Please check this link related your questions https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156410/magento-2-get-pub-static-file-path

Answer (score 1):

use  `Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository`

```
 $asset = $this->assetRepository->createAsset('Magento_Catalog::images/image.png');
 $asset = $this->assetRepository->createAsset('My_Module::images/image.png');
```

> app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/

```
$asset = $this->assetRepository->createAsset('images/image.png');
```

use  `Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File`

```
// Get the file url
$asset->getUrl();

// Get the file path
$asset->getFilePath();

// Get the content of the file
$asset->getContent();
```